# Duplicated WP site manually, now links redirect wrong

Tags: redirect

So, I duplicated my website (by just duplicating the VM in Proxmox under another name) so I could use the local duplicate to test settings and develop the site. I have edited the database, changed the site URL from wp-config.php and everything kind of seems to work.

The page address is now just an IP address, but when I click a link on the site, the address "duplicates" itself. If I click a link called "about", the address changes from 127.0.0.1 to 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1/about. If I click another link on the About page, this causes an infinite loop of redirections. I get

> The 127.0.0.1 page isn’t working. 127.0.0.1 redirected you too many times.

and the page address is an endless loop of the IP and page addresses. I have no idea what causes this, could anyone help?
Note: the actual address isn't 127.0.0.1, but an internal network address. I just used that for the sake of the question.

Comment: How did you edit the database?

Comment: @MaxYudin with phpMyAdmin.

Comment: You should use [Search Replace DB](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) or a migration plugin.

Comment: @MaxYudin That's unfortunately not possible due to IS reasons. Do you think this is an issue related to our actual domain that's still somewhere in the database?

Comment: Yes, it's very likely.

Comment: @MaxYudin I installed the "WP Migrate DB" plugin and did a Find&Replace of the database. No luck still.

Comment: That means there is no WordPress problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue: in `wp-config.php`, there was no http:// before the address on the `define('WP_HOME'` line.
From [Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Edit_wp-config.php):

> Add these two lines to your wp-config.php, where "example.com" is the
>   correct location of your site.
>
> `define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');`
>   `define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');`

Adding these properly solved the issue.